# Pandoc markdown: default colour for inline verbatim

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Is there a way to set the default colour of inline verbatim snippets (`...`) in Pandoc markdown? For example, that all the verbatims in a document will be red instead of black?

I know, I can do, e.g.

```
Normal text `verbatim`{.bash} normal text
```

for syntax-highlighting the verbatim snippet. However, what I want is a simple default colour for all verbatim snippets.

I use pandoc for converting to PDF via LaTeX, and I use a LaTeX template. I can make any changes to the LaTeX template, if this allows to enable this behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandoc converts `verbatim` content into `\texttt{}` in LaTeX. You could redefine this command to style it:

```
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

% overwrite \texttt command to use coloring
\let\oldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\oldTexttt{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```

If you include the snippet above in your LaTeX template, your pdf will contain red `verbatim` content.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Just a typo in the last line, `\OldTexttt` should be `\oldTexttt`.